# c++ premier code not giving correct output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
       int cnt = 1;

       while (std::cin >> val)
       {

          if (val == currVal)
          {
             ++cnt;
          }

          else 
          {
             std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times"; 
             std::cout<<std::endl;
             currVal = val;
             cnt = 1;
          }
       }
       std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;

   }
   return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to input few integers and answer how many times each integer occurs consecutively. Note that this code has been directly copied from the book c++ premier.

for input-
42 42 42 69 69 50 50 50 100 100 100

It gives output-

```
42 occurs 3 times
69 occurs 2 times
50 occurs 3 times
```

It is ignoring the 100s at the last.

Note that there is a line of code outside the while loop specifically to output the last inetger
.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please indent the code. All but impossible to follow without that.

Comment: How do you terminate the code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code. 100 is not showing how many times has been entered because of the way that you had to exit from the while loop (ctrl+c perhaps).

Instead what you can do is to have a terminating number (-1 for example) if the user enters the terminating number then you exit, this way you won't have to exit the loop with ctrl+c.

@john suggested the following: you can exit by entering something that doesn't parse to a number, a character for example.

Comment: The terminating number is clearly 0. The issue will be the termination was done through ctrl+z.

Comment: You could also enter something that can't be parsed as a number

Comment: @john yes, I will add your suggestion.

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney the code executes perfectly, we are discussing the exit method from the while loop because in that website you can specify exactly what gets entered. In a terminal, you will get different results because you will need to manually terminate the while loop.

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney how is it not working in codeblocks then? I am new to coding. Pls forgive my silly doubts.

Comment: @Croolman 0 doesn't terminate the loop, the loop will keep going when you enter 0 because cin returns true or false depending on whether correct input was passed to the stream.

Comment: @bhristov Oh, you re right. Forgot about that `cin` returns `istream`

Comment: @JayantJha because there is (probably) `EOF` when run in `ideone` and `cin` failed then break the loop. you can try redirect a file as input to see the same behavior. (like `myprograme.exe < testfile.txt`)